# Fetch data from database based on checkbox on button click

Tags: c#, database, buttonclick

I have table consisting columns(....,....,....,BLOCK) in my database.
The BLOCK column has bit datatype(True,False).
When BLOCK column has False, the data should be fetched from the database.
When BLOCK column has True, the data should not be fetched resulting in throwing an error.
When I give the name of a particular person in textbox and click button, the above operation must be performed

my button click c# coding is...

```
 protected void ImageButton5_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{

    string selectsql = "SELECT * FROM UserDetailsTwo";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=ENTERKEY001;Initial Catalog=ContactManagement;Integrated Security=True"))//DataBase Connection
    {
        SqlCommand selectCommand = new SqlCommand(selectsql, con);
        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader SelectReader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();
        while (SelectReader.Read())
        {

            Boolean BLOCK = Convert.ToBoolean(SelectReader["BLOCK"]);
            if (BLOCK == false)
            {

                //con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "SearchUser";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", TextBox4.Text.Trim());
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                da.Fill(dt);
                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();
                con.Close();
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("Error");

            }
        }
        SelectReader.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is Error ??did you debug code??

Comment: It throws an error telling "ERROR CONVERTING DATATYPE NVARCHAR TO BIGINT" on the 12th line of my code(While ststement line).

Comment: It is giving me an error telling "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first." on my 28th line (da.Fill(dt);)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use an SQLDataReader like a DataAdapter.

```
SelectReader = selectCommand.ExecuteReader();
while (SelectReader.Read())
{

          Int64 BLOCK = Convert.ToInt64(SelectReader["BLOCK"]);
          if (BLOCK == false)
          {

              con.Open();
              SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
              cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
              cmd.CommandText = "SearchUser";
              cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NAME", TextBox4.Text.Trim());
              SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
              DataTable dt = new DataTable();
              da.Fill(dt);
              GridView1.DataBind();
              con.Close();
          }
          else
          {
              Response.Write("Error");

          }
      }
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Same error on the same line(while (SelectReader.Read()))

Comment: What is the datatype of ID in the table? And where are you defining the variable ID?